# completed web application, reinstalled operating system now can't connect to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was learning more about ASP.NET MVC, and I decided to to take a course on Udemy taught by Mosh Hamedani, and this course involved me making an application called Vidley. I was able to complete the course entirely, however I came across a problem:

A day or two after I completed the course. My computer caught a virus and I had to reformat the operating system and reinstall everything. I had the application backed up on bit bucket, but the application just doesn't work with the database. When ever I try to create a new user, the application just throws an error. What do I need to do to get the application working with the database again. I tried looking at other topics but I couldn't see anything that covered my specific issue. I am thinking if there is any kind of configuration I need to fix with the database, but I am not entirely sure and I am concerned I will break the code.

It really is upsetting because I was going to add that project to my portfolio, so I could find a job easier. I am wondering what I have to do to get this web application to work with the database again, and where should I deploy it. Should I use a website like app harbor, or is there any other better platform. I am really new at this so I am sorry if I am asking an absurd question.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: check database server instance is running

Comment: Edited the tags on your question, presumed you're using c# please re-edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: probably its because the connectionstring properties.

Comment: I am convinced it has a lot to do with the connection string properties in the web config file. What I did was I saw the database in the application, but all of the data was cleared out. I am not sure if this was natural or not, because I did back up the data files on bit bucket. When I view the properties of the database it is the same as what is in the configuration file except for one difference. Instead of having |DataDirectory| in the properties it show the literal file path the database is located in.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any other procedures I must do because once again, I did reformat my computer and everything is new, and I just simply got all the code from Bit Bucket.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please recheck your connection string as you have reinstalled everything even the operating system.
2. Check your Database server instance is running or not. If not, start that service.
3. Recheck database name, username and password in your connection string.

Comment: Okay I followed the instructions. What I also did was I saved all of my work on cloud storage and when I pulled the codes from my cloud storage it is working for some reason. As of right now the application does work in debug, but I am having issues deploying it to App Harbor but that is complete different issue I am resolving. Is there any other service aside from App Harbor I could deploy my website to for free.

Comment: @Daniel Some years ago, I used [MyAsp.net](http://www.myasp.net/). they still give free hosting. I have no other service on my mind right now.